# ASP.Net session debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there any tool or sth to view Session with all key values elements in debug mode?

I can use immediate Window to check but I need to know Key. I would like to have clear view of what is actually in the session,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regular debugging tools, or perhaps a small custom output form etc you can easily loop through each session value using the [Keys property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.keys.aspx) of the session object in a for loop printing each value...

that would retrieve all the values currently stored in session.

Some code (pseudo-ish):

```
foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
{
    // Session[key].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Watch window. Just type in "Session", hit enter and navigate through the tree.